# How can i become obsessed with some meaning to life that i find rational?

Tags: psychology, meaning-of-life, kierkegaard, camus, absurdism

-**Background**:

I see something for example like living for others or trying to change the world (in a non-violent way) is an genuine meaning to life,however i'm not obsessed with these meanings that i see rational. What i want to suggest is that, we exist in two psychological states, either depressed or obsessed. The so-called "normal" majority are just as obsessed as maniacs, but they are obsessed with cultural dogmas and projects. The question is not are you obsessed or not, it's how many people agree with and accept your obsession or how common is it? 
What i mean is that, one should have faith in something to be free from despair.
Unfortunately for me, i reject any cultural view.  Now i need to have an alternative sustaining life project, for my despair to end. I know that Camus did not have any possibility or hope, and in the same time, he was not depressed as i am. But what i m advocating here, is that he should have made something out of his dreadful realizations, some concept or dogma that sustained him, as for example writing books and telling about his findings. It's like saying his dogma was "reject all dogmas". It was superficially anti-dogmatic but down deep it was as any dogma. Unfortunately for me also, this doesn't work for me. Offcourse, there are people who are happy without being obsessed about something, here's where pleasure comes to action: as  Leo Tolstoy, in his book "A Confession" (in which he describes his existential crisis), noticed that there are a majority of people that relay on pleasure rather than faith. Unfortunately, pleasure is not a solution for me.

-**Question**:
How can i become obsessed with some meaning to life that i find rational?

-**Problem**:
I think this is what kierkegaard meant by "Belief" and "Faith": The belief is me believing that X is a rational meaning to life.The faith is the obsession with the belief. But the problem is that "Faith is a matter of grace", it's a random thing that man can't choose or reach by himself.

Comment: Vote to close because this is not a question... it is more of an opinion-piece.

Comment: no it's not. I showed my opinion but i really wish that it's not true and there is a way through this.

Comment: That still does not make it a valid question for Philosophy SE. Plus I have issues with the structuring and format of the question. You should arrange it something like this: **Background**, **Problem**, **Query**. The **background** is where you let us know the necessary information that explains what this question is about. The **problem** is where you explain the issue you have, the issue that you need to solve. The **query** then is the actual question, that — if answered — solves your problem. Try that, and see if it turns into a more valid post.

Comment: this does sound interesting but it is definitely structured more as an opinionated stance rather than something we can "answer"

Comment: At first, try investigate the meaning of life itself (big bang, abiogenesis, animal life, mind...). You are part of this life flow, and meaning of your personal life depends on meaning of life in general.

Comment: I'd call this a pre-philosophical question since a study of philosophy may be the answer to it. I wouldn't see faith or belief as an answer since, as you say, one cannot just switch-on a belief or faith in order to solve a problem. I feel you'd need to think a lot more about philosophy, religion, life the universe and everything.    ,

Comment: Everything here depends on how you define "obsessed". Because, for most common meanings of "obsessed", *many* happy people go through life *without* being "obsessed" about anything at all.

Comment: Here's where pleasure comes to action, Leo Tolstoy, in his book "A Confession" (in which he describes his existential crisis), noticed that there are a majority of people that relay on pleasure rather than faith. Unfortunately, pleasure is not a solution for me. @Chelonian

Comment: @Chelonian

Also keep in mind, that, an obsession can be anything such as some cultural trivial matter , for example , having a favorite football team.

Comment: @Themobisback Can "having an obsession" also be working a normal job you like, having a significant other and/or family you care for, living in a comfortable home, and passing free time doing various little enjoyable things, like books, movies, walks, etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure there is philosphical answer, like the answer for question "How can I stop the depression?". If you reject any meaning, then others can't give it to you.

Comment: @Chelonian What i'm saying is there are two ways that mask depression and fear that people relay one 1)pleasure 2)self-esteem (feeling of personal significance)

In your example, if that person is not dependent on pleasure, then he must be making something out of his achievements which are culturally accepted and motivated achievements as you noted, for example "I have a family, therefore i'm more successful and significant than who does not", that person in the example is obsessed with his culture values. he's taking them for granted.  what i mean by "obsessed with" is "sustained by".

Comment: @Themobisback Given that, you might want to incorporate this response to me into your question, since it clarifies it quite a bit since I know no one that would ever describe such a person as "obsessed with his cultural values".You've also admitted here that there are not only two states, "depressed" or "obsessed", but also a third, "in pleasure", and "pleasure" can mean simple Epicurean pleasures like chatting with a friend, having a coffee, looking at an apple tree in bloom, etc.

Comment: @Chelonian how i see this pleasure, is a practice like sex,drugs,video games and tasty food. It's not a state like depression or faith(what i call obsession). But it supplies a temporary sustaining effect as that of faith.

Comment: @rus9384 i m not rejecting all meanings, but i can't have faith with what i believe is a rational meaning.

Comment: @Themobisback, do you want rational meaning? Like Kant? Rational meaning is to exist and evolve. That does not necessarily mean to have children, that means positively contribute to society.

Comment: @Themobisback Then it seems your model of human well-being is impoverished. Feel free to start a chat and invite us to help you round that out, but it's not good to have extended discussion in Comments.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77581/meaning-of-life

Answer (score 1):

seek out the truth. search for it in all places. explore all religions and all philosophies. don't leave any stone unturned.

Comment: Would you have any references to help explain your answer?

Comment: @FrankHubeny personal experience

Answer (score 0):

In Judeo-Christian scripture there is an ancient text that seems to start in just the same way your question starts: "Everything is meaningless!!!"  Here is an excerpt:

> The words of the Teacher, son of David, king in Jerusalem:
>   “Meaningless! Meaningless!”
>       says the Teacher.
>   “Utterly meaningless!
>       Everything is meaningless.”
>   What do people gain from all their labors
>       at which they toil under the sun?  *[Ecclesiastes 1:1-3, NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes%201&version=NIV)*

And then in Chapter 2:

> I said to myself, “Come now, I will test you with pleasure to find out what is good.” But that also proved to be meaningless. “Laughter,” I said, “is madness. And what does pleasure accomplish?” I tried cheering myself with wine, and embracing folly—my mind still guiding me with wisdom. I wanted to see what was good for people to do under the heavens during the few days of their lives.
>
> I undertook great projects: I built houses for myself and planted vineyards. I made gardens and parks and planted all kinds of fruit trees in them. I made reservoirs to water groves of flourishing trees. I bought male and female slaves and had other slaves who were born in my house. I also owned more herds and flocks than anyone in Jerusalem before me. I amassed silver and gold for myself, and the treasure of kings and provinces. I acquired male and female singers, and a harem as well—the delights of a man’s heart. I became greater by far than anyone in Jerusalem before me. In all this my wisdom stayed with me.
>
> I denied myself nothing my eyes desired;
>       I refused my heart no pleasure.
>   My heart took delight in all my labor,
>       and this was the reward for all my toil.
>
> Yet when I surveyed all that my hands had done
>       and what I had toiled to achieve,
>   everything was meaningless, a chasing after the wind;
>       nothing was gained under the sun.
>
> Then I turned my thoughts to consider wisdom,
>       and also madness and folly.
>   What more can the king’s successor do
>       than what has already been done?
>
> I saw that wisdom is better than folly,
>       just as light is better than darkness.
>
> The wise have eyes in their heads,
>       while the fool walks in the darkness;
>   but I came to realize
>       that the same fate overtakes them both.
>
> Then I said to myself,
>
> “The fate of the fool will overtake me also.
>       What then do I gain by being wise?”
>   I said to myself,
>       “This too is meaningless.”
>
> For the wise, like the fool, will not be long remembered;
>       the days have already come when both have been forgotten.
>   Like the fool, the wise too must die!
>
> So I hated life, because the work that is done under the sun was grievous to me. All of it is meaningless, a chasing after the wind. I hated all the things I had toiled for under the sun, because I must leave them to the one who comes after me. And who knows whether that person will be wise or foolish? Yet they will have control over all the fruit of my toil into which I have poured my effort and skill under the sun. This too is meaningless. So my heart began to despair over all my toilsome labor under the sun. For a person may labor with wisdom, knowledge and skill, and then they must leave all they own to another who has not toiled for it. This too is meaningless and a great misfortune. What do people get for all the toil and anxious striving with which they labor under the sun? All their days their work is grief and pain; even at night their minds do not rest. This too is meaningless.
>
> A person can do nothing better than to eat and drink and find satisfaction in their own toil. This too, I see, is from the hand of God, for without him, who can eat or find enjoyment? To the person who pleases him, God gives wisdom, knowledge and happiness, but to the sinner he gives the task of gathering and storing up wealth to hand it over to the one who pleases God. This too is meaningless, a chasing after the wind.  [*Ecclesiastes 2:1-26*](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiastes%202&version=NIV)

Comment: Well, Ecclesiates is one of the most ancient scripture that is similar to absurdism.

Comment: Ecclesiastes was referring to things "under the sun", i.e. physical matters. not spiritual matters